# Cannot assign value for completionInterval attribute (of aggregate tag) from properties file: Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have a camel code snippet in the form:

```
<aggregate strategyRef="aggregationStrategy"
     completionSize="50" completionInterval="120000">
...
</aggregate>
```

I am trying to read the attribute values from a properties file by following the link http://camel.apache.org/properties.html.

Currently, I have defined propertyPlaceholder through which I am able to assign value for completion size (by referring it through an endpoint) through properties; as below

```
<propertyPlaceholder id="properties" location="classpath:file.properties" />
<endpoint id="compSize" uri="{{completion.size}}" />
...

<aggregate strategyRef="aggregationStrategy"
         completionInterval="120000">
    ...
    <completionSize>
         <simple>ref:compSize</simple>
    </completionSize>
    ...
</aggregate>
```

But if I follow the same procedure (as that of `<completionSize>`) to set completionInterval, it throws an error since we don't have a tag like `<completionInterval>`.

**Is there a way to assign value for completionInterval attribute dynamically, through properties file ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this as a dynamic expression in the aggregator

```
<aggregate ...>

   <completionInterval>
      <constant>{{somePropertyKeyHere}}</constant>
   </completionInterval>
```

Or use the `prop` namespace to set the value as documented in the *Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL* section of http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: This is not working for me.  The Camel schema is not allowing for completionInterval to be an XML element, only an attribute.  In the following camel email thread - https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Setting-dynamic-completionInterval-in-aggregator-td5719671.html - you say its not possible.  Is this a new feature?  Am I misreading your comments?

Comment: Ah yeah completion interval can not be dynamic